# How to show custom message in window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

How to show custom message in `window.onbeforeunload` ? By default, it is showing as attached image. I need to show Don't Refresh instead of Cancel, and Refresh Anyway instead of Leave. I have tried but failed.

```
Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                html: 'You are about to save a session named',
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                timer: 999999,
                didOpen: () => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                    const b = Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('b')
                    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                        b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                    }, 100)
                },
                willClose: () => {
                    clearInterval(timerInterval)
                },
                timerProgressBar: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Save',
                cancelButtonText: 'Continue edit'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {

                }
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        };
```

Comment: I do believe there are some browsers (depending on the version) that specifically don't allow customisation of that "before unload" prompt.  You might be stuck with what you get

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, these days, you can't.

Most browsers do not allow it, because it was abused in the past by spammers and malware sites.